# What is this columnar evergreen tree with yellow-green foliage?

Tags: identification, evergreens

I need to buy some more of these for other places around the garden.

What are these called?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't get enough magnification to examine the needle arrangement properly, but at a guess, it could be Cupressus macrocarpus Wilma, link below to an image, but you'll have to click on the pic itself to see it larger

http://www.treemail.hu/noveny_enciklopedia/cupressus_macrocarpa_wilma_aranysarga_oszlopos_monterey_ciprus

Comment: I think that's correct. It's also often sold as Arborvitae

Comment: I thought Arborvitae referred to Thuja? I can't help thinking it'd be a helluva lot easier if you guys used the proper names - mind you, I say the same here in the UK to people who live here!

Comment: Is Arborvitae a catch all term meaning just 'conifer' in the States?

Comment: I am sorry, you are 100% correct

Comment: Erm, what, that Arborvitae refers specifically to Thuja, or that its a catch all term for conifer?

Comment: Well I was referring to it being thuja, but to be quite honest and not coy at all, you second statement as well.

Comment: Ah, so that means if someone asks a question about Arborvitae without a photograph, I wil have no idea what plant they mean other than its being some random variety of conifer? Up to now, I've assumed you guys in the States mean Thuja with that term, but from what you're saying, its anybody's guess...

Comment: I knew someone who was calling a deciduous shrub arborvitae. I can't remember the sheub precisely because it was some years ago but it had leaves similar to perhaps Poplar or American Maple (also called Alder I think).

Comment: You are right though, we have more than one name for many species. For instance hibiscus and rose of Sharon. American maple and alder, white walnut and butternut, the list goes on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30059/discussion-between-bamboo-and-escoce).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a lemon cedar, this is called in this way by people because it smells like lemons, you can touch it to see if it smells like lemon if not is another variety of cedar.

Comment: Sorry!, the last answer is correct and has the scientific name that was not familiar to me, I just verified it [here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupressus_macrocarpa_var._goldcrest)

Comment: Hi! No problem about your initial thought-thanks for the verification of the correct answer! I see you've been around the network a bit. Welcome to this site, hope to see you again!